# Instagram Task Bot is firing event to quickly

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to delay when the first picture is clicked because it is clicking the picture before the screen loads, while the picture is getting clicked the modal is not appearing. I am console logging if the picture has been clicked and it is true but the modal doesnt appear so i am guessing it is happening too quickly. If i run the function without coming from the home page everything works fine. Please Open Instagram in your browser and run either of the functions in your console and you will see what I mean.

SetInterval and  DOM content loaded I have tried

```
// Instagram hacks

//  Search field
// let Searchtest= prompt("Please enter the hashtag you want to like","Trending");

// var search = document.querySelector('.x3qfX').value = "#" + Searchtest;

document.querySelector(".glyphsSpriteSafari__outline__24__grey_9").click();

var firstPicture = document.querySelector("div._9AhH0");

var elementIsClicked = false; // declare the variable that tracks the state
 function clickHandler (){
   elementIsClicked = true;
 }

 firstPicture.addEventListener('click',clickHandler)
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",firstPicture.click())
 console.log(`The first picture has been clicked = ${elementIsClicked}`);


let likesGiven = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  let heart = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9"
    ),
    arrow = document.querySelector(".coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow");

  if (heart[1] && elementIsClicked) {
    heart = heart[1].parentElement;
    likesGiven++, heart.click();
  }
  arrow.click();
  console.log(`You've liked ${likesGiven} post(s)!`);
}, 2000);

// Button Liker
```

SetTimeout

```
// Instagram hacks

//  Search field
// let Searchtest= prompt("Please enter the hashtag you want to like","Trending");

// var search = document.querySelector('.x3qfX').value = "#" + Searchtest;

document.querySelector(".glyphsSpriteSafari__outline__24__grey_9").click();

var firstPicture = document.querySelector("div._9AhH0");

var elementIsClicked = false; // declare the variable that tracks the state
 function clickHandler (){
   elementIsClicked = true;
 }

 firstPicture.addEventListener('click',clickHandler)
 setTimeout(firstPicture.click(), 5000);
 console.log(`The first picture has been clicked = ${elementIsClicked}`);


let likesGiven = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  let heart = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9"
    ),
    arrow = document.querySelector(".coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow");

  if (heart[1] && elementIsClicked) {
    heart = heart[1].parentElement;
    likesGiven++, heart.click();
  }
  arrow.click();
  console.log(`You've liked ${likesGiven} post(s)!`);
}, 2000);

// Button Liker
```

Comment: Have you tried making the function asynchronous?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

`setTimeout(firstPicture.click(), 5000);`

into:

`setTimeout(firstPicture.click, 5000);`

You should be passing a reference to a function. Currently, you are calling the function and referencing the return value of the function.

Comment: So put It in a function then call the function?

Comment: and setTimeout(firstPicture.click, 5000);

 is wrong it doesnt click anything

Comment: Would you be able to set up a small jsfiddle/jsbin/pencode program? That would help a lot.